# How to recover Kafka from complete zookeeper loss and new start?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a simple Kafka cluster of 3 brokers and 3 zk nodes.

If I wipe out 2/3 zk nodes and bring them back (even new "clean" ones), everything recovers as zk re-syncs.

If I wipe out all 3 zk nodes and restart them "clean" (think docker containers or AWS auto-scaling group instances), the brokers are confused. All of the data structures in zk (basic paths, brokers, topics, etc.) are gone, since I have a blank zk.

How can I recover from this scenario? I am (potentially) willing to live with lost topics (since we automate topic creation), but the brokers (unlike with startup) do not "know" that zk is blank and so do not reinitialize (set up structures, register brokers, etc.). Conversely, I could back up zk and restore it, as long as I know what to backup/restore.

The key element is fully automated, though. In cloud-native, I cannot rely on a human doing the restore or checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that managing Zookeeper nodes (or Kafka brokers for that matter) with autoscaling is such a good idea.

For one Zookeeper maintains the topic information (and if you are not using the latest Kafka builds or are sill using the *old* consumer API it also maintains the consumer offsets).

In addition to that topic partitions are statically assigned to brokers, so if you bring down the current Kafka brokers and spawn new nodes you have to be very careful and start brokers with the same `broker.id` and data otherwise Kafka might get confused.

Third regarding Zookeeper you have to be careful not to create a cluster of a pair number of nodes otherwise the consensus algorithm will not be able to elect a leader due to missing majority in the voting phase.

Having said all that I think that doing a backup and restore of one of the Zookeeper nodes should work. It would be even easier if you set up things so that at least one of the nodes cannot be turned off (or alternative you use a persistent storage for that one).

This way you ensure that one of the Zookeeper nodes will always have the latest data and it will take care of replicating it to the other nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the detail @nivox. Essentially what you are saying is, "ZK and Kafka don't play very nicely in auto-scaling worlds." Not a judgment, just a reality. But if I have to, then backup/restore of zk nodes is the best (least bad) way to go, unless I have some form of persistent storage. Is that it? For backup, you would just regularly copy the latest snapshot off somewhere, and on startup, if new cluster, restore it?

Comment: FYI, I do tightly control it. ZK nodes and Kafka brokers do have consistent IDs and hostnames, and we do stick with the odd number ZK nodes.

Comment: @deitch You summed it up correctly. Regarding the restore of Zookeeper you can just stop the service, copy the entire zookeeper data directory and that's it. Once you spawn up a new cluster, you put that backup in the data directory of the first node you spawn up and you're set to go. Note that this will bring back Zookeeper with the *old* state, so the Kafka cluster must match it or you will have problems.

Comment: If I were you however I would invest in some stable storage for these services, you do not want to risk and have your Kafka topics broken because your backup procedure messed up.

Comment: It isn't a matter of investing, as architecture. I try to avoid real-time persistent storage wherever possible. Sometimes I have no choice, but when I do, and can use local fast storage/memory for everything, app-level replication, and backup/restore, I do.

Comment: So... I don't need to use the snapshot files? Just copy the `/data` dir? Then why do I have snapshots?

Comment: For data I meant both the directory containing the *snapshots* as well as the directory containing the *logs*. You need both of them to recover the last state.

Comment: Fair enough. So `/data` and `/datalogs`. Will do. Thanks again.

Comment: To be clear, I need to set up the `/data` and `/datalog` *before* restarting zk, right?